# Server side redirect truncating request payloads

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, c#-4.0, iis-6

I'm on IIS 6 and I have an ASP.Net 4.0 site that's a single page to serve as a SOAP reverse proxy. I have to modify the return content in order to delete a trouble node from the response and add a tracking node.

In order to facilitate its function as a reverse proxy for all addresses, I have the 404 on the server set to a custom "URL" of "/default.aspx" (the page for my app)

For requests without a payload, it works perfectly - such as for ?WSDL Urls. It requests the proper URL from the target system, gets the response and sends it back - it's pretty utterly transparent in this regard.

However, when a SOAP request is being made with an input payload, the Request.InputStream in the code is always empty. Empty - with one exception - using SOAPUI, I can override the end point and send the request directly to /default.aspx and it will receive the input payload. Thus, I have determined that the custom 404 handler is - when server-side transferring the request - stripping the payload. I know the payload is being sent - I have even wiresharked it on the server to be sure. But then when I add code to log the contents of Request.InputStream it's blank - even though Request.ContentLength shows the right content length for the original request.

I've also been looking for a good way to use ASP.Net to intercept the requests directly rather than allowing the normal IIS 404 handler to take care of it but even with a wildcard mapping, I can't seem to get the settings right nor am I fully confident that it would help. (But I'm hoping it would?)

Finally, I don't have corporate permission to install MVC framework.

Thus, I need either some configuration for IIS I am missing to make this work properly or some other method of ensuring that I get the request payload to my web page.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using an HTTP Handler mapped to all requests?

You'll need to add [a wildcard application mapping as detailed here](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/windowsserver2003/library/iis/5c5ae5e0-f4f9-44b0-a743-f4c3a5ff68ec.mspx) and correctly [configure your HTTP Handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46c5ddfy%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Looking - I'll get back to you!

Comment: You sir - are a GENIUS! I was trying of course to use an aspx and a 404 handler as described above - not really aware of the HTTP Handler method you linked. I changed the code over with the help of the articles you linked (and a follow up one that one of your links had a link to: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228090.aspx ) and IT WORKS! Thanks so very much!